# Why does the increment/decrement in a for loop not end with a statement?

Tags: java

Everywhere else I write a statement in Java I need to end it with a semi-colon. However, that doesn't apply to the i++ of a for loop.

How comes?

Comment: Because the `i++` of a for loop is an *expression*, not a statement.

Comment: I believe `if` conditionals can also contain statements without semicolons at the end: `if(found = set.contains(key))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's special syntax with clear and agreed-upon semantic meaning interpretable by the compiler, because the designers of C/C++/Java/etc. arbitarily decided it should be so.

EDIT:

Some commenters have pointed out that the decision isn't really arbitary, since designers did it to maintain consistency with expression vs. statement syntax. I'm glad they pointed that out, because I didn't know that was the case. In my defense, they very clearly could have made the syntax require a semicolon in that position; the decision not to, while not entirely arbitrarily, represented a choice which could have been different. Ahem.

Comment: No, because it is expression and not a statement. `someFunc(i++)` is basically the same.

Comment: @Andrey: And the reason it's someFunc(i++) is because it's special syntax with clear and agreed-upon semantic meaning interpretable by the compiler, because the designers of C/C++/Java/etc. arbitrarily decided it should be so. More seriously, I feel my answer isn't entirely out of line since it would apply equally well to questions asking the same thing about C/C++.

Comment: @Patrick87 - not to be pedantic BUT ... there are words with specific meanings in specs. `expression` and `statement` being two of them. I think what Andrey was trying to point out is that it isn't an arbitrary decision at all.

Answer (score 2):

Because the ')' rather well terminates the update statement so it would be redundant?

Answer (score 1):

Both in C and C++ it's like that, and Java copied much of the syntax of those languages, for making things easier for programmers coming from them.

Also, it really isn't necessary to end the statement with a ";", since the right parenthesis ")" demarcates where the statement ends.

Answer (score 1):

I would spend some time learning the differences between an expression and a statement; as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html).

The parts of a `for` loop are *expressions*, not statements. Expressions are not terminated by semicolons. `i++` is an expression. Likewise, you don't put a semicolon after the i++ here:

```
System.out.println(i++;);
//                    ^ wrong
```

That wouldn't make any sense. The same logic applies to `if`, and `while` loops.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, really two of the three terms in a  for loop aren't really statements.  Take the canonical for loop

```
for(int ix = 0; ix < MAX; ix++){ /* do something */ }
```

that's really shorthand for

```
int ix = 0;
while(ix < MAX){ /* do something */ ; ix++; }
```

Notice that there's no semicolon for `ix < MAX` either.  In the for loop, the semicolons are simply there to separate the terms somehow -- only by co-incidence (and a lack of extra symbols) is it the same as a statement terminator.